# How to execute if there's a certain block within a radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to figure out how to execute (for example /say hi) when there's Yellow Terracotta in a certain radius or field, however I can't figure out how to do it. Anyone knows?

Answer (score -1):

I provided some thoughts in your [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658387/how-to-execute-if-theres-a-certain-block-within-a-radius/65676530#65676530) on stackoverflow, but I came up with (for mc1.16):

```
execute at @p[distance=..3] if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta run say hi
```

This sort of achieves what you are looking for. When a button is on the command block, the player must press the button, be within 3 blocks of the command block, and the terracotta must be under the player. Then it shall run "say hi."

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think this will help me. I want to have some sort of Lava Spleef system, where each block gets calculated and seen for how long it exists.

Comment: @BjornGmr In your other thread, I mentioned that it is possible to check an individual location for a block. If you string these together in a function (to check several locations), you could constantly tick the function and perhaps each command could do something to a scoreboard... It's very rudimentary and not efficient. But that is all I can think of.